# Combining table records

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a DB with three tables and negligible knowledge of SQL syntax

Table 1;

```
  person_id;
  person_name;
```

Table 2;

```
  thing_id;
  thing_name;
```

Table 3;

```
  action_id;
  action name;
  thing_id; (referencing thing_id in the table 2)
  person1_id(referencing person_id in the Table 1);
  person2_id(referencing person_id in the Table 1);
```

Basically, I need to combine display 1st person name, 2nd person name, action name and thing name. Could I be directed to some correct join way for this?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Thanks, I am still not sure how to condition the display of both persons' names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select 
    action_id,
    action name,
    a1.thing_name,
    p1.person_name as person_name1,
    p2.person_name as person_name2
from table3
left join table1 p1 on p1.person_id = table3.person1_id
left join table1 p2 on p2.person_id = table3.person2_id
left join table2 a1 on a1.thing_id = table3.thing_id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select t3.action_id,
       t3.action_name,
       t1.person_name,
       t2.person_name
from table3 t3
inner join table2 t2 on t2.ting_id = t3.ting_id,
inner join table1 t1 on t1.person_id = t3.person1_id,
inner join table1 t2 on t2.person_id = t3.person2_id
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL SERVER it would be something like this, you might have to adapt it slightly for mysql.

```
SELECT p1.person_name AS first_person_name, p2.person_name AS second_person_name, t3.action_name, t2.thing_name
FROM
    table3 t3
    JOIN table1 p1
        ON p1.person1_id = t3.person_id
    JOIN table1 p2
        ON p2.person2_id = t3.person_id
    JOIN table2 t2
        ON t2.thing_id = t3.thing_id
```